# Replacing row values in multiple columns from cascaded table join

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have SQL tables in below format, I was figuring whats the best approach to navigate and join tables to get to the final result. I can do it in Python as well since this seems to require join on multiple columns which would end up duplicating rows.

Any tips?

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2 and Table 3 have different number of digits in Account.

Table 2:

[image]

Table 3:

[image]

Table 1 - With new columns that is needed after navigating from Table 2 and Table 3 to fetch the data into Table1.

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  The logic for what you are doing is also not obvious.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to combine tables 2 and 3.  The logic is not 100% clear, but something like this

```
with t23 as (
      select t2.account, concat(t3.account, ' - ', t3.desc) as desc
      from table2 t2 join
           table3 t3
           on t2.desc = t3.desc
     )
select t1.*, t23_1.desc, t23_2.desc, t23_3.desc
from table1 t1 left join
     t23 t23_1
     on t1.c1 = t23_1.account left join
     t23 t23_2
     on t1.c2 = t23_2.account left join
     t23 t23_3
     on t1.c3 = t23_3.account;
```

I am not sure if `t23` is being defined by fiddling with the account column.  However, joining on `desc` seems more obvious.

Also, `desc` is a very bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword (think `order by`).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I'll check this.